# Complexity of a 2d Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: c#, complexity-theory, fft

I have a question regarding a 2D Fourier transformation. I'm currently in the progress of understandig the maths behind this, and there's something I dont onderstand. As far as I'm concerned, the DFT has a complexity of `O(N*N)`. If I look at the following algorithm:

[image]

I don't understand how it works. Are we going to do this caluculation for every pixel in the tranformed *image*?

**example**

1. We have an image of 2*2.
2. For each pixel in this image we're going to do the DFT *F(x,y)*
3. I'll create a new image, and each pixel is the magnitude of the corrosponding complex value

Is this how it works or am I missing something? Because the way I see it now, it has a complexity of `O(N^4)`

Comment: And the relevance of C#?

Comment: I thought it just might be nice to add this, since I don't know if functional programming languages might treat this calculations differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation means "to get the value of F at pixel (u, v), evaluate (the formula on the right-hand-side)."  So, to get the entire transformed image, it's evaluated for every pixel in the transformed image.

To compute a DFT, using the formula, you need to do an O(1) calculation for every input value for every output value.  (There are other, faster algorithms for some kinds of data.)  In your 2D DFT case, the algorithm has complexity O((M*N)^2), because the number of input pixels is M*N and and the number of output pixels is also M*N.

**edit**: A 2D matrix DFT can be calculated in O(NM^2 + MN^2) by transforming the rows and columns in separate steps.  The algorithm is here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Image_Processing/node6.html

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that! I however have one short question left before I can start programming. Do you perhaps now what (ux/M+vy/N) exactly mean?

Comment: According to ( http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Image_Processing/node6.html ) the complexity of 2D DFT is O(N^3)

Comment: @RobS I was describing the complexity of the given DFT algorithm.  The algorithm you linked is indeed asymptotically faster.  I added it to the answer.